# Add Table in Existing PDF in Page Bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am working on a Approval workflow where certain approvers approves the document. The Number of Approvers varies in each Approval Request.

I want to Place a Table in the document being approved. The table should have the columns who have the images of  signatures of each Approver.

I've successfully edited the Document using ItextSharp and added text Water Mark as described in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274864/add-water-mark-on-pdf-spfile/274916#274916). Now I am trying to Place a table in PDF Documet using PDFStamper but the table is not visible when I Print the Document.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btn_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt_comments = obj_comments.GetRequestComments(ViewState["DocumentNumber"].ToString());                  
            SPFile pdfOriginalFile = obj_RequestDocuments.GetFile(ViewState["DocumentNumber"].ToString());   

        //get byte[] of uploaded file
        byte[] contentPdfOriginalFile = pdfOriginalFile.OpenBinary();

        //Initialize PdfReader
        var reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(contentPdfOriginalFile), null);

        //We will write output file into memory. You can use temp file of course.
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        //Initialize PdfStamper
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);

        //Tell stamper not to close stream when stamper itself is being closed
        stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

        // Getting total number of pages of the Existing Document
            int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;

            // Create New Layer for Watermark
            PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("WatermarkLayer", stamper.Writer);
            //************CREATE TABLE START***********************
            PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(dt_comments.Rows.Count);   

                    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                    table.SetTotalWidth(ColumnWidths(dt_comments.Rows.Count,200f));

                    for (var i = 0; i < dt_comments.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        var image = dt_comments.Rows[i];
                        try
                        {
                            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                            cell.BorderWidth = 15;
                            cell.FixedHeight = 15;
                            cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;                                  
                            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

                            float offset = 0;


                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            sb.Append(dt_comments.Rows[i]["Action"] + " By:");
                            sb.Append(dt_comments.Rows[i]["CommentBy"].ToString());
                            sb.Append(" On " + dt_comments.Rows[i]["Created"].ToString());
                            p.Add(new Chunk(sb.ToString()));
                            cell.AddElement(p);
                            table.AddCell(cell);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Ignore
                        } 
                    }

            //**************CREATE TABLE ENDED************************
            // Loop through each Page
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                // Getting the Page Size
                Rectangle rect = reader.GetPageSize(i);

                // Get the ContentByte object
                PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);

                // Tell the cb that the next commands should be "bound" to this new layer
                cb.BeginLayer(layer);
                cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(
                  BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 8);

                PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();

                gState.FillOpacity = 0.3f;
                cb.SetGState(gState);

                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                cb.BeginText();
                 float width = rect.Width;
                float height = rect.Height;


                float HorizontalValue =width/6 ;
                float verticalValue =height/6;


                //for (int j = 0; j < dt_comments.Rows.Count; j++)
                //{
                //    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                //    sb.Append(dt_comments.Rows[j]["Action"] + " By:");
                //    sb.Append(dt_comments.Rows[j]["CommentBy"].ToString());
                //    sb.Append(" On " + dt_comments.Rows[j]["Created"].ToString());

                //    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, sb.ToString(), HorizontalValue, verticalValue, 0f);
                //    verticalValue = verticalValue - 10;//to change the line come down
                //} 
                //cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Confidential", rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, 45f);

                PdfTemplate tableTemplate = cb.CreateTemplate(1500, 1300);
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, table.Rows.Count, 400, 400, tableTemplate);


                cb.EndText();

                // Close the layer
                cb.EndLayer();


            }



        //Close stamper, readed
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
        //obj_RequestDocuments.UploadFile(pdfOriginalFile.Name, ms.ToArray(), "1234");
        string[] stringParts = pdfOriginalFile.Name.Split(new char[] { '.' });
        string strType = stringParts[1];
        Page.Response.Clear();
        Page.Response.ClearContent();
        Page.Response.ClearHeaders();
        Page.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfOriginalFile.Name);
        //Set the content type as file extension type
        Page.Response.ContentType = strType;
        //Write the file content
        Page.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        Page.Response.End();

        //Flush memory stream and set it position to start
        ms.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;

        }
```

Please note that currently I am trying to simply add Approver name in Each column, the next step would be to add the image of Approver's signature in each column

When I was adding simple text in the document it was successful but I am unable to add the table in the document and puzzled in fixing the width Height issues as the document size could be A3 or A4. Currently I am testing it on A3

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35550776/assign-dynamic-pdfpcell-width-to-dynamically-generated-pdfpcell)

**UPDATE:**

I Modified the following method call, now the table is visible but in Black color fill, nothing is visible:

```
table.WriteSelectedRows(0, table.Rows.Count, 400, 400, cb);
```

I've also placed White in place of Black in the following line:

```
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
```

Also, there is an Error when I open the PDF generated from the above code:

Following is the Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: You create a template, you add content to the template, but you don't put the template anywhere...

Comment: @mkl Thanks  for your suggestion. please see my update

Comment: Please share the result file for analysis.

Comment: @mkl I have placed the screen shot of the file

Comment: By "result file" I mean the pdf itself, not a screen shot. There is not much to analyze in a screen shot...